# Source Code For lightning-formatted-address?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I can see the source code for a bunch of the LWC base components [here](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc), but where is the one for [`lightning-formatted-address?`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-address/example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not in the base components, there's no easy way to see the source. I've used the [Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en) and the plain old Developer Console (Google Chrome) to see the source, but you need to enable [Lightning Debug Mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm), which slows down the UI, but provides a better debugging experience.